# Update a Google docs on Google Drive by api

Tags: python, api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to create a Google Docs on Google drive, with some text inside the Docs. I'm already creating the Docs via api, but i only can update a blank archive.

Does anyone know how to update the text inside the doc and/or add the information when the docs is created?

This piece of code creates the blank docs in python:

```py
doc_metadata = {
    'name': 'docs_name',
    'parents': [f'{folder_id}'],
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
}

try:
    doc = drive_service.files().create(body=doc_metadata).execute()
    documentId = doc.get("id")
except HttpError as error:
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

```
#Authentication
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']

doc_metadata = {
    'name': 'docs_name',
    'parents': [f'{folder_id}'], #FolderID
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
}

#Service Builder
service_docs = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)
service_drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

#Creating document file using the drive API
try:
    doc = service_drive.files().create(body=doc_metadata).execute()
    DOCUMENT_ID = doc.get("id")
except HttpError as error:
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
     
new_text = 'This is a sample sentence for the newly created document'

requests = [
    {
        'insertText': {
             'location': {
                 'index': 1,
              },
              'text': new_text
            }
    }
]

#Inserting text using insertText request from Google docs API
result = service_docs.documents().batchUpdate(
documentId = DOCUMENT_ID, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

To insert text into a document, use the `BatchUpdate` method and include an `InsertTextRequest` with the text and location as the payload.

Moreover, you need **Drive API to create document** and **Docs API to edit document.**

***Reference:***
[Insert, delete, and move text](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text)